# Javascript: Get sibling of current element [needed for CKEditor]

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Hey, I am working on a simple Plugin for CKEditor, I am not to firm with JavaScript, so here is my problem.

I upload an image and insert it with a dialog, producing something like this.

```
<div class="float-right image">  
<img alt="alt-text" src="img.jpg" />   
<span class="caption">Caption</span>  
</div>
```

Works like a charm, but once i is inserted I want to be able to edit it.
Doing so I can get the alt attribute and the src of the image via

```
var elem = this.getParentEditor().getSelection().getSelectedElement();
```

and working with getAttribute('...'). But I can not figure out how to reach, the caption and the div.

I would be very happy if you could help me. Thanks in advance.

BTW: Is there a possibility to use jquery within a plugin for CKEditor?

### Heres the solution:

So what I came up with in the end, thanks to all the help here.
In the dialog part:

```
onShow : function()
{
elem = this.getParentEditor().getSelection().getSelectedElement();
var span = elem.getNext();
var parent = span.getParent();
}
```

this gives me all the stuff I need to fill into the dialog once I open it again.

to submit everything I needed to find out how to change the current selection. This works like this:

```
onOk:
function()
    {
editor.getSelection().selectElement(editor.getSelection().getSelectedElement().getParent());
editor.insertHtml('<div ...</div>');
}
```

Thank you guys, I only started digging into the CKEditor Plugins today and already I got two nice ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the CKEditor API you can use [.getNext()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.node.html#getNext)

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that helped me all the way. Is there an easy way to find those commands? By Trial and error I found .getParent too, well it was a well informed guess.

Comment: You can find them in the page that I've linked

Comment: Awesome, sorry, I assumed that was just a hightlight by stackoverflow, like thoses infolinks. Did not click it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use jQuery within a CKEditor plugin as long as you don't intend to distribute the plugin (other people may not have jQuery), in which case your solution becomes:

`$(elem).next('span')` and `$(elem).prev('div')`

If you don't want to use jQuery, you have .nextSibling and .previousSibling

Note, however, that the next and prev siblings will often be textNodes depending on what browser you're in.  So to get the span, you need a loop:

```
function getNextSibling(node, type){
    while((node = node.nextSibling) && (node.nodeName != type));
    return node;
}

getNextSibling(elem, 'SPAN');
```

Answer (score 1):

There's Element.nextElementSibling, which is supported in IE9+, Fx3.5+, Op, Saf, and Chrome (dunno versions for the last three, but for quite a while).